# Maximum, minimum, rate of change behavior of $H(t)=t^6-\frac{3}{4}t^8$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm stuck on this problem involving open intervals and absolute maximum/minimum.

$$H(t)=t^6-\frac{3}{4}t^8$$
On what intervals is the function increasing? Decreasing? What are the absolute maximum? Minimum?

Comment: I see that you have to use test points, but I don't understand the process

Comment: Note that because $H(t)$ only involves even powers of $t$, we have $H(t)=H(-t)$. So our curve is **symmetrical** about the $y$-axis. That will help as a check on the correctness of your calculations. For example, the function is decreasing on $[1,\infty)$, so it must be increasing on $(-\infty,-1]$.

Comment: Here is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173604/monotonocity-of-the-function/173622#173622).

Answer (score 7):

$$H^{\prime}(t)=6t^5-8\cdot \frac{3}{4}t^7 = 6t^5 - 6t^7 = 6t^5(1-t^2) = 6t^5(1-t)(1+t).$$

> When is $H^{\prime}(t) = 0$?

- These are points you need to look at to determine the maximum and minimum values of $H(t)$. There are three distinct values of $t$ at which $H^{\prime}(t) = 0$.

> On what intervals is the function increasing? Decreasing?

- Examine the behavior of $H(t)$ within each of the four intervals separated by the points at which $H^{\prime} = 0$.
- On which intervals is $H^{\prime}(t)>0\;$? On these interval(s), $H(t)$ is increasing.
- On which intervals is $H^{\prime}(t) <0\;$? On these intervals, $H(t)$ is decreasing.

Recall, the derivative of a function corresponds to the "*rate of change*" of the function.

---

To "see" the function's behavior, see [$H(t)$ on WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28t%29%20=%20t%5E6%20-%20%283/4%29t%5E8). Note the "action" going on in the interval, say $x\in (−1.5,1.5)$ that might easily get overlooked when graphed, depending on the scale of the $x$-$y$  axes.

Comment: Nice analysis and CONGRATULATIONS on 50K!!!!  Well deserved! +1

Answer (score 0):

The sign of the derivative $H^\prime(t)$ tells you where the function is increasing and decreasing.  If $H^\prime>0$, it's increasing.  If $H^\prime<0$, it's decreasing.  So, the first thing to do is find $H^\prime$.  Then, make a "sign chart" for $H^\prime$ - basically a number line that shows where $H^\prime(t)$ is positive, negative and zero. Below is an *example* of a sign chart (this isn't the sign chart for your function!!) [image: This isn't the sign chart for your function, just an example of what it should look like!]

You find these signs by 'testing' points between your zeros.  To find the extrema, you have to look at the values where $H^\prime=0$ then use the second derivative test and so on to classify them.

Answer (score 0):

$H´(t) = 6 t⁴ \cdot t \cdot (1-t)(1+t)$. Then we can see that $ H´(t) >0 $ in $ (- \infty,-1) \cup (0,1) $   and $ H´(t)<0 $ in 
 $ (-1,0) \cup(1,+\infty) $. Thus $ H $  increases in $ (- \infty,-1) \cup (0,1) $, decreases in $ (-1,0) \cup(1,+\infty) $ and possui maximum in $ H(1) = H(-1) = 1/4 $. Finally, how $ \lim_{t\rightarrow + \infty}H(t)= -\infty$. $ H $ does not have minimum.